# Suspending simplification of integral

Tags: maxima

Suppose we have the following code:

```
integrate(a*x/a,x);
```

How can we run this code without any simplification, so that we can get the LaTeX equation without any simplification:

```
$\int\frac{ax}{a}dx$
```

?

Comment: Paul, it looks like dratenik answered your question, that's great. Can I ask for what purpose you are doing this? Any info about the larger goals you're working towards would be very interesting. FWIW I'm a Maxima developer and project administrator, so I'm always interested in what people are doing with Maxima.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertDodier, for your question and interest! Via package `rim`, I use Maxima to generate multiple-choice questions in R with package `exams`. And therefore I need to write both the answer and the unevaluated integral, say. To do both things in Maxima is safer and faster than writing the LaTeX formula separately. Before using Maxima, I did that with R package `caracas` (an R interface to Python `Sympy`), but inhibiting evaluation was too tricky and a lot of trial-an-error.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It turns out that there have been several projects, larger and smaller, to use Maxima as the basis for a system which generates problems and evaluates answers. At this point it seems like it could be beneficial to somehow coordinate or at least share results between such projects; not sure what that would look like. Something to think about!

Comment: Thanks, @RobertDodier. Maxima helps a lot to create several distinct versions of the same question. For instance, `integrate(a*x/2,x);` can give us several different questions by replacing `a` by different integers. And all this can be automated with R package `exams` and `vim` (R interface to Maxima).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the simplifier with:

```
simp:false;
```

before evaluating the integral. Don't forget to enable it afterwards.

The [manual](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_45.html) mentions this as an "extreme option". Presumably a lot of other functionality will be broken while it is off.

Another way (maybe you neeed both?): single quote before the expression. This one prevents evaluation but not simplification. See also: https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_43.html

Comment: Thanks, @drateni! That works for the particular example I gave you. Unfortunately, it seems not being a general solution: For instance, it gives an error when we try to run `limit ((x^2 - 1)/(x^2 + 1), x, inf);` with `simp:false;`

Comment: @PaulSmith That one works better with a single quote `'limit ((x^2 - 1)/(x^2 + 1), x, inf);` which was not enough for the integral. Maybe you want both?

Comment: Perfect, @dratenik! Thanks!